# Latex IEEE template: Use single column table in multicolumn latex content

Tags: templates, multicol, ieeetran, journal-publishing

I am trying to use this IEEE [template](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/52fb869c33621a613683ec74) to write a report. I don't see any package named `\usepackage{multicol}` which is used for multi-column. So I can not change it from two column to single column. Problem is, I have a big table which need whole page without two column. That is, my table should be in single column with whole page. You can see the example image. Sorry for bad image. Also, I have to use this template to write my report. [image]

Comment: you can try `\begin{table*}
\caption{if needed}\label{if caption}
\begin{tabular}{...}
...
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}`

Comment: I know how to add table, I don't know how to merge from two column to single column in my mentioned template

Comment: `table*` uses both columns! If it doesn't help use `\onecolumn .... \twocolumn` but that always starts a new page.

Comment: starting in a new page is not a problem but after table I can't show any content in that page. Contents after table start in a new page. How can I prevent that. I want the content to start right after the table end.

Comment: I have vted as a duplicate since it doesn't matter if it is a fifure or a table. This should solve your proble, if not, please provide a MWE?